# Can I save the inverse of a pose?

Tags: armature

For a number of reasons, I sometimes like to lock my model into an armature modified pose (for editing, visualization, etc).  Most recently, I wanted to do this to fit clothes in a different pose from my body base, followed by a weight transfer.  (I apply my armature modifier, apply my pose as resting pose to the armature, and then recreate my armature modifier, to "write" the pose to the model and armature.)

However, it can be difficult to recreate my original pose to restore the model (and my newly fitted, weighted clothes) to its original pose.  Is there a way to save an inverse of an existing pose, that I can apply to an armature to undo a pose that I've written into the mesh+armature?

Comment: You can save the original armature duplicate in the original pose and then use it as a guide to snap to for your new armature with new base pose.

Comment: Thanks jerryno, that's what I've done so far, but it's not as perfect or painless as I'd prefer.

Comment: Well you can also script this into an operator with python. You have access to the bone's matrices in original pose and in the new rest-pose. The only issue is bone scaling, but you have head tail distances to rectify that.